# Import my visual webpart to my site I get error; "$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, safe-controls

When I import my visual webpart to my site I get error; "$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;".
My solution has WCFService project and visual webpart calls WCF service. 
I have added my webpart to SafeControl.

```
<SafeControl Assembly="WCFService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2f18b97447e16bc" Namespace="WCFService.VisualWebPart1" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True"/>
```

Comment: Double check Namespace, Assembly Name (strong assembly name), and add ***Safe Against Script*** property

Comment: It was added by system.